# Can we deploy ionic 1 app using latest version?

Tags: ionic-framework

I am able to build ionic 1 app but it is not working fine. I am building my ionic 1 app with latest version of ionic. I don't know what is exact reason for this. Can you help me on this?.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Ionic 1 with latest version . What does  it's means ? Latest version is Ionic 3 and u hv build app in 1 . Framework is different .How u can do that ?

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing you are using the latest version of the ionic CLI and a project with ionic 1 library installed?

The latest ionic CLI works with ionic 1 javascript libraries.